# SwiftUI Keyboard dismiss not interactive

Tags: swift, swiftui, keyboard-events

Thanks for taking your time to help others :)

### Problem description:

**App must support iOS 14 (there's no keyboard toolbar), and cannot use Introspect library, sorry.**

When using a TextField, I want to dismiss it interactively. It does dismiss the keyboard, but does not take TextField along. And it should.

### Simple demo code to replicate what happens:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""

    init() {
        UIScrollView.appearance().keyboardDismissMode = .interactive // To interactively dismiss
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(1...200, id: \.self) { msg in
                        Text("Message \(msg)")
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.red.cornerRadius(8))
                    }
                }
            }

            TextField("Hello", text: $text)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .padding()
        }
        .navigationTitle("Example")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

### GIF resources to see behaviour:

1. Good result:
   [image: Good result]
2. Bad result:
   [image: Bad result]

### What I have checked?

Registering the keyboard height through Notifications events, like in: [this post](https://programmingwithswift.com/get-keyboard-height-swiftui/) and adding that height as offset, bottom padding... nothing works.

Any idea?